# How to create a answer to a watson assistant intent on NODEJS app?

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I need to create a answer to a intent on watson assistant, there's a way to get the list of intents and assign a response to a specify intent ? im using watson-developer-cloud@3.18.1 and NodeJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is but you will need to use the V1 API - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1?code=node#update-dialog-node

If your dialog node already exists then you can update it. If it doesn't then you will need to create it, as well as position it in the dialog - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1?code=node#create-dialog-node